# Ubuntu 9.10 upgraded with Internet connection fail

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, internet-connection

I am pretty sure that the latest Ubuntu release does not support my wireless internet card. Everything was working fine in 9.04 and since upgrading my browser will load web pages. I can see and connect to my wep encrypted network. I can ping google.com and lose no packets.

I am at the end of my tether, what else can I try? Is it possible to download a driver to re-enable my wireless?

Comment: Try again at superuser.com. This is in no way programming related and will get closed.

Answer (score 1):

If ping works just fine then ubuntu definitely supports your card.

So lets focus on the browser.  I'm guessing (just guessing) it's firefox.  Please verify you can 'wget google.com' just fine, and that either safari or opera or both work just fine.

I'll guess you were running an older version of firefox previous to the upgrade.  Recently they changed how they interact with DNS and this could be nailing you.  The new DNS prefetch logic can be disabled; here's an overview of how to do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/controlling_dns_prefetching

Please let us know if this helped- if other browsers work, and indeed if the DNS prefetch was causing the problem; it's just a guess on my part.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer right away. During this time, I skipped 9.10 entirely, I had a similar problem during an upgrade to Lucid Ubunutu 10.04. Where firefox wouldn't load pages. So I ran about:config in the address bar and took a risk editing  some options. I disabled useip6 and it works fine. I think it's my router!

Comment: That complete correction was to set network.dns.disableIPv6 to true.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked under Administration>Hardware Drivers to see if there is a driver that Ubuntu has found.